# API Level specific code for Notifications gives errors for min required api level

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to get my app to give out notifications, but since the min api level is 11, I have to use this code:

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        // call something for API Level 16+
        Notification noti;

        noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("New Notification from LCD")
                .setContentText("content")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Option1", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Option2", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Option3",
                        pIntent).build();
        NotificationManager nmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // hide notification
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        nmanager.notify(0, noti);
    }
```

I have another one set up for API levels under 16, using the .getNotification() instead of .build().

Even after that I'm getting the `Call requires API level 16 (current min is 11)` error. What can I do to fix this?

EDIT: Forgot to add, the .getNotification line is giving a yellow error saying `The method getNotification() from the type Notification.Builder is deprecated`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` annotation.
For example, the method below that detects whether the device has a physical menu button:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static boolean hasMenuButton(Context ctx) {
    return (
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10 || 
        (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 && ViewConfiguration.get(ctx).hasPermanentMenuKey())
    );
}
```

EDIT (further to OP's edit):
And similarly, you can get rid of the deprecation warning using the `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` annotation. For example, the method below that uses some code needed under API11 but deprecated after.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void initializeSurfaceHolder() {
    final SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();

    holder.addCallback(this);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that worked! So all that does is stop it from checking for errors of that type?

Comment: Of course it does :) And yes, exactly. It is a way to tell the compiler that you are aware of what you are doing.